# Open file in current instance of Visual Studio when running under different credentials

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I work on a project which is hosted in IIS, and therefore in order to debug this site I have to run Visual Studio as an administrator.

The problem is, when opening a file in Windows Explorer, I would like to open it in the current instance of Visual Studio (or a new instance if that is not the case).

I've had partial success, using a batch file with the following contents:

`cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE"
devenv /Edit %1`

However, this opens Visual Studio as the currently logged-in user, and NOT as Administrator (so when I have an instance already open as administrator it opens a new instance anyway).

So the question is; how can I have the file open in the current instance, as Administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Shift+right-click on the file in Explorer
2. Press 'a' on the popup menu (selects Copy As Path)
3. Switch to Visual Studio
4. Press Ctrl+O then Ctrl+V then Enter

You could probably make some kind of [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to automate it, depending on how often you need to do this.

Comment: Interesting answer, although I was hoping to find a way to do this by simply double-clicking the file in windows explorer, and without the use of third party macro apps. I'm going to hang  off marking this as the answer in the hopes that someone has a better suggestion. :p

Comment: @AdamDrewery: Well, you can't do that because of UAC. Lower privilege processes cannot interfere with higher privilege processes. So when you explicitly elevate an application, Explorer cannot communicate with it via double-click or drag+drop. See here for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/01/28/q-why-doesn-t-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi.aspx

Comment: Guess that's the best answer I'll get given my current setup, I don't have UAC enabled but I guess the User Interface Privilege Isolation is still running and blocking messages between MIC levels. Cheers. :)